# Autosuggestion In Flask Api

Tags: python, pandas, ajax, flask, flash

I am creating a Flask API, for movie Recommendation i have dataset and i want autosuggestion functionality when i type any letter i will get movie related to that word.

This my app.py file:-

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
from flask_cors import CORS
import pandas as pd

item_similarity_df = pd.read_csv("movie_similarity.csv", index_col=0)

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/")
def hello_from_root():
    return jsonify(message='Hello from root!')

@app.route("/recms", methods = ["POST"])
def make_rec():
  if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.json
        movie = data["movie_title"]
        #curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:8080/recms -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"movie_title":"Heat (1995)"}'
        try: 
            similar_score = item_similarity_df[movie]
            similar_movies = similar_score.sort_values(ascending=False)[1:50]
            api_recommendations = similar_movies.index.to_list()
        except:
            api_recommendations = ['Movie not found']
        return render_template("index.html",api_recommendations = api_recommendations)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

This is my index.htlm:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AutoComplete</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js">  
    </script>  
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js">  
    </script>  
    
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to GFG</h1>
    <input type="text" id="tags">
    
    <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
        {% for api_recommendations in api_recommendations %}
            "{{api_recommendations}}",
        {% endfor %}
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Code is executing fine and i am getting;-{"message":"Hello from root!"}

but when i am executing:- curl -X POST http://10.0.0.72:8080/recms -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"movie_title":"Heat (1995)"}' i am getting recommendate movie but i want if i type instead of "Heat (1995)"
[image]
i am getting rec. movie but i want if i type instead of "Heat (1995)" only h it will give all the movie name with h letter.

Answer (score 1):

The following example uses AJAX to search for entries in the DataFrame whose title column contains the substring that was sent.

A GET request is sent to the server for each substring entered. This searches for rows whose title column contains the string, ignoring upper and lower case. Matching rows are then extracted, sorted by title, and collapsed to the title column. All titles are returned as a list in JSON format.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    jsonify, 
    render_template, 
    request
)
import pandas as pd
import re 

app = Flask(__name__)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['Heat (1995)'], 
        ['Rock, The (1996)'], 
        ['Casino (1995)'], 
        ['Rumble in the Bronx (1995)'], 
        ['Léon: The Professional (1994)'], 
        ['Desperado (1995)'], 
        ['Twelve Monkeys (1995)'], 
        ['Broken Arrow (1996)'], 
        ['Platoon (1986)'], 
        ['Leaving Las Vegas (1995)'], 
        ['Fargo (1996)']
    ], 
    columns=['movie_title']
)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/lookup')
def lookup():
    query = request.args.get('query')
    data = df[df['movie_title'].str.contains(query, flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
    data = data.sort_values(by=['movie_title'], ascending=True)['movie_title'].tolist()
    return jsonify(data)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="titles">Title</label>
        <input id="titles" />
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#titles').autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
                    $.get({{ url_for('.lookup') | tojson }}, { query: request.term }, 
                        function(data) {
                            response(data);
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```